# Add BCC in Magento Transactional Email

Tags: magento

I created a new email template, and that works fine in Magento, but I don't know how to add BCC addresses to the email.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the answer I've found:

```
 $mailTemplate->setTemplateSubject($mailSubject)->addBcc('youremail@mail.com')
->s‌​endTransactional($templateId, $sender, $email, $cus_name, $data, $storeId);
```

Answer (score 13):

You can add a bcc in the code where you send the email:

```
Mage::getModel('core/email_template')
     ->addBcc('em@ail.com')
     ->sendTransactional(...
```

Comment: How to send bcc to multiple email addresses using same code?

Comment: You can pass an array to the addBcc function.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it in the config. Go to Sales > Sales E-Mails. Foreach transactional E-Mail you can enter `Send Order Email Copy To` and set the Method to BCC via `Send Order Email Copy Method`.

Comment: Thankyou for your reply..But i need to send email copy only for my custom email template.

Comment: I got the solution $mailTemplate->setTemplateSubject($mailSubject)->addBCC('youremail@mail.com')->sendTransactional($templateId, $sender, $email, $cus_name, $data, $storeId);

Comment: It seems i posted the answer at the same time you found the solution yourself. The main thing is that you have the solution finally.

Answer (score 1):

single email or array email is acceptable, check this :

> app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Email\Template.php

```
Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template

public function addBcc($bcc)
{
    if (is_array($bcc)) {
        foreach ($bcc as $email) {
            $this->getMail()->addBcc($email);
        }
    }
    elseif ($bcc) {
        $this->getMail()->addBcc($bcc);
    }
    return $this;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create di.xml: `app/code/Py/Custom/etc/di.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="\Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder">
        <plugin name="TransportBuilderPlugin" type="Py\Custom\Plugin\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder" sortOrder="1" />
    </type>
</config>
```

Create Plugin: `app/code/Py/Custom/Plugin/Mail/Template/TransportBuilder.php`

```
<?php

namespace Py\Custom\Plugin\Mail\Template;

class TransportBuilder
{
    public function afterGetTransport(\Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder $subject, $result)
    {
        $result->getMessage()->addCc('test@gmail.com');     
        return $result;
    }
}
```