# Add replyTo in Magento Transactional Email

Tags: magento, magento-1.9, transactional-email

What I'm trying to do is to add a replyto field to the core transactional emails of magento. Something like what was archieved in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14641673/add-bcc-in-magento-transactional-email) with bcc, but for replyTo. Any ideia?

Update:
Just to clarify this a little. In the magento TEMPLATE class it is possible to add the replyTo header (core function), but in the MAILER class it is not possible to do that. And that is what I need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There’s no need to extend any class.

Just use:

```
$mailTemplate = Mage::getModel('core/email_template');
$mailTemplate->setReplyTo('test@example.com');
$mailTemplate->sendTransactional($templateId, $sender, $recipient, '', $vars, $storeId);
```

Answer (score 2):

So I manage to solve this by extend the MAILER class.

- Arround line 74, function send(), you need to add `$emailTemplate->setReplyTo($this->getReplyTo());`
- Also add this to functions to this same class:

  `public function setReplyTo($replyto) {
      return $this->setData('replyto', $replyto);
  }
  public function getReplyTo() {
      return $this->_getData('replyto');
  }`

  - Lastly you just need to call this setReplyTo when you to set the replyTo (:P) on your extension.

    `$mailer = Mage::getModel('core/email_template_mailer');`

Thank you VladFR, but I wasn't able to figure out how to implement what you sugested.

Comment: Can you mention filename and location of that file as well to change?

Answer (score 1):

Reply-To is a standard email header: [RFC 5322](http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5322.txt), section 3.6.2, and it has the form

```
"Reply-To:" address-list
```

So you can add it just as you would add a custom header:

```
$mail->addHeader("Reply-To", "reply.to@example.com");

//Mage has addReplyTo() depending on version
$mail->addReplyTo('email@example.com', 'Name');
```

Also see [Zend Documentation for Zend_Mail](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.mail.additional-headers.html), which is what Magento uses.